# java.lang.Exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7

Tags: java, matrix

I am trying to store each line of a file into a String array.

```
/*
*Input file
*2 1 1 1 1 1 1.33 1
*4 2 15 3 9 3 0.185
*/

String[][] data_array = new String[1][7];
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
//file read
StringTokenizer tokenizer =new StringTokenizer(line,delim);
while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
    String token = tokenizer.nextToken();
    data_array[i][j] = token;
    j++;
}
```

But showing

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
```

But When I am trying with

```
String[][] data_array = new String[1][8];
```

I am not getting this exception instead I am getting below as the output.

```
2 1 1 1 1 1 1.33 1 null
4 2 15 3 9 3 0.185 null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java, arrays are 0-based, that is the first element will have index `0` and the last element will have index `n - 1` (where `n` is the length of the array).

As your array is declared `[1][7]`, the last index will be number `6`. Your first row contains 8 values, therefore you end up trying to load the 8th value (index 7) into an array containing 7 elements. Using index `7` results in an `IndexOutOfBoundException`.

Moreover, in your particular case, the first row of the input contains 8 elements, but the second row only contains 7 elements.  If you try to load 7 values into the array containing 8 elements, the last one will be `null`.  For the input you specified, with array declared as having length 8, the output would be:

```
2   1   1   1   1   1   1.33    1
4   2   15  3   9   3   0.185   null
```

(Note that I added extra spaces to indicate better how the array is populated.)

Further, it makes little sense to declare a two-dimensional array with the first dimension being 1 - it's the same as declaring a single-dimension array.  What you probably want to do is have an array with first dimension referring to rows in the file and second dimension referring to values in rows.

Answer (score 0):

The elements of an array with length *i* are numbered *0* to *i-1*.

I assume you are using blanks as delimeters. Is there a trailing blank at the end of the line? This would explain why you are getting one surplus token.

Comment: If by blank, you mean a space, why would it shown null in this case? Unless the op is not showing us something and this is after doing a number conversion.

Comment: The StringTokenizer returns a token for each delimeter it finds. If a delimeter is located at the end of the given String it returns null, as there is no content left after the delimeter.

Answer (score 0):

you must use array in  your method not in the body of your class!

and arrays first element have index=> 0  and the lastest element have index=> N-1